# read all images from the folder and convert it to a single channel image and save it

Tags: python-3.x

I want to save the single channel image from RGB image When I take one image it will works but when I take multiple images the I got problem

```
from glob import glob
import os 
import numpy as np
def load_data(path):
    img_list = []
    for img in glob(os.path.join(path,"*.jpeg")):
        image = cv2.imread(img)
        img_list.append(image)  
    return img_list    
p = load_data(path)
path = 'F:/EyePac/eye/class/Train_1'
img_array = np.array(p)
rgb = img_array[1]
r = rgb_r.copy()
r[:,:,1]=0
r[:,:,2]=0
```

Comment: What's the exact problem?

Comment: I want to convert all images into green channel images  and i can't save the image in a folder

Comment: I want to convert all images into green channel images. I take 50 images from them when i take only one image i can convert into single channel image but when i take all image it does n't work  i take the image in the  img_array when i try to img_array [:,:,1]=0 i got error

Comment: To make this easier for people to help, please update your question to include: (1) Exactly what you are trying to do (as like the text you mentioned here in the comments) (2) include the error message you are talking about; this will help people to understand where the problem is. In general, try to include as much relevant information as you can in your questions, with error messages, description of what you want to do and what the problem is. :)

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-15f9d3522212> in <module>()
      1 rgb_r = img_array[2]
----> 2 rgb_g = img_array[:,:,1]
      3 #rgb_b = img_array[:,:,2]
      4 r = rgb_r.copy()
      5 r[:,:,1]=0

IndexError: too many indices for array